# Failed to connect with redis in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am trying to connect with `redis`(of docker instance) using `express(node.js)`.
Here is my `index.ts` file in which i am trying to connect with `redis`

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis'
import Redis from 'ioredis'
import { MONGO_URI, MONGO_OPTIONS, REDIS_OPTIONS, APP_PORT } from './config'
import { createApp } from './app';

; (async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, MONGO_OPTIONS)

    const RedistStore = connectRedis(session)

    const client = new Redis(REDIS_OPTIONS)

    const store = new RedistStore({ client })

    const app = createApp(store)

    app.listen(APP_PORT, () => console.log('server running on port 3000'))
})()
```

Here is my `REDIS_OPTIONS` file in which i have all `redis` options.

```js
import { RedisOptions } from 'ioredis'

const {
    REDIS_PORT = 6379,
    REDIS_HOST = 'localhost',
    REDIS_PASSWORD = 'secret'
} = process.env

export const REDIS_OPTIONS: RedisOptions = {
    port: +REDIS_PORT,
    host: REDIS_HOST,
    password: REDIS_PASSWORD
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```js
version: '3'

services: 
  db:
    user: $UID
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT: ''
      MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD: ''
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: auth,
      MONGO_USERNAME: ''
      MONGO_PASSWORD: ''
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh:ro
  
  cache: 
    image: redis:alpine
    ports: 
      - '6379:6379'
    command: ['--requirepass "secret"']
```

`package.json`

```js
{
    "name": "node-auth",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "up": "docker-compose up -d",
        "postup": "npm run dev",
        "stop": "docker-compose stop",
        "down": "docker-compose down",
        "dev": "npm run dev --prefix api"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Now when i try to run my main app file so i am getting this error

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14) node.js
```

How can i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a problem with the Redis container. What command you used to run the container? Try adding `-p 6379:6379` with your docker command. Also, check whether port 6379 is used by something else or blocked by antivirus or firewall.

Comment: If you have trouble changing config inside container, you can download the default redis config from here: http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf then copy it in the same folder where docker-compose.yml is, edit the file as follows: look for line "bind 127.0.0.1" and replace with "bind 0.0.0.0" (without quotes), and edit docker-compose.yml with a new volume tag with this:
`volumes:
 - redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`

Comment: have done all steps that you said. But still getting an error

Comment: Then, I am assuming problem is related to multiple virtual network interface cards, and localhost being resolved to a different virtual NIC than the one Docker is using. Are you using Windows?

Comment: Open command prompt and use `ipconfig` and see what is the address of the NIC that is used for Docker. Then, in your REDIS_OPTIONS, change REDIS_HOST to that NIC's IP Address.

Comment: What do you mean by NIC? ?

Comment: you mean IP address ?

Comment: IP Address is a property of a NIC. :) Similar to MAC address and it's name.

Comment: I might have unintentionally confused you, just to clarify, you need to find the entry of the NIC that is used by Docker, and yes, you need to note down the IP Address of that NIC. And googling should be able to tell you how to find what NIC is being used by Docker.

Answer (score 0):

change host in index.ts from 'localhost' to 'redis'